# I want to put my text file into an array word by word instead of line by line

Tags: python, list, text-files

I'm working with big data files that have different stats per word. I want to separate these words into their own array by stat.

I've used `readline()` but that is too long. The data in my file is in paragraph form and is not indented for every line.

```
for i in range(1, 169):
    date.append(filename.readline().rstrip(','))
    num_of_games.append(filename.readline().rstrip(','))
    day_of_week.append(filename.readline().rstrip(','))
    vteam_league.append(filename.readline().rstrip(','))

date = [20180405,20180406, 20180407, 20180408]
num_of_games = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Can you give a short example of the data file?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a comma-separated file. Use the [Python CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library to read in the file. Something like

```
import csv

num_of_games = []
date = []
day_of_week = []
vteam_league = []
with open(filename) as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         date.append(row[0])
         num_of_games.append(row[1])
         day_of_week.append(row[2])
         vteam_league.append(row[3])
```

Comment: Do I need to declare date, num_of_games, etc. as lists before I do this?

Comment: Yes, I added that above